# Trying to get database data using NODEJS to insert into a graph

Tags: javascript, node.js, plotly, ejs

First of all, I'd like to thank all those that try to help us students. It's not an easy task at all!

I'm trying to get a column from an SQL database to be printed out in a graph (Plotly.js)... I have the route set up, it is sending the info I need to the view (EJS) and I am trying to use it on the graphs, but after some days of research, I couldn't find an answer...

This is the code just for the route:

```
    app.get('/barras', function(req,res){
    console.log('Database connection online');
    connection.query('select progresso from barra', function(error,result){
        barras = result;
        console.log(barras);
        res.render('admin/barras',barras);
    });
});
```

The information is going to be used on this view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Plotly.js -->
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<% if(barras){ %>
  <ul>
    <% for (var i = 0; i < barras.length; i++) { %>
      <li>
        <%=barras[i].progresso %>
      </li>
    <%}%>
  </ul>
<% } %>
  <div id="myDiv" style="width: 480px; height: 400px;"><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
  <script>
var data = [{ 
     type: 'bar', 
     x: [barras[i].progresso],
     y: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'], 
     orientation: 'h' 
}];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I put the "for" structure above just to be sure that the information was being sent, and it is...

Comment: barras[i].progresso doesn't exist outside the for loop, does it? I think you would need to pass x: [barras[0].progresso, barras[1].progresso, barras[2].progresso]

Comment: barras exists in the route above, on the line res.render - so the .ejs file receives the variable barras with the JSON object extracted from the database... The for loop is printing the numbers from barras correctly. I just don't know how to put it inside the graph on the X axis... :(

Comment: `var data = [{ 
     type: 'bar', 
     x: [barras[0].progresso, barras[1].progresso, barras[2].progresso] ,
     y: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'], 
     orientation: 'h' 
}];` I was talking about this chunk ;)

Comment: Oh right! But still, what if we have dozens of information? Would we still need to put every single index? That is my doubt... And it didn't get the value of the indexes. And to help, no error report as well! haha

Comment: Good god! I've just called college to get some help from my professor and...     var barras = <%= barras[0].progresso %>
    console.log(barras);
 data = [{ 
     type: 'bar', 
     x: [barras],
     y: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'], 
     orientation: 'h' 
}];

This works! So the same idea is used for the names of each progress bar. The thing is declaring the variable before the graph, and then using the variable in the graph.